If $K$ is a perfect field, then the invariant field of all its automorphism is a perfect field too.
I was asked as an exercise to proove the statement above:

If $K$ is a perfect field, then the invariant field for its automorphism group is a perfect field too.

So, if $G=Aut(K)$ and $K$ is a perfect field, then it must be proven that $K^G$ is a perfect field too (if I did not understand it wrong).
My first idea was thinking that the $K^G$ must be the prime field of $K$, and I did not come to anything. Is this wrong?
My second seems too easy. The "perfection" of a subfield seems too obvious using the Frobenius automorphism ($K$ is perfect) as the restriction to $K^G$ will be the identity and therefore also an automorphism, impliying then that $K^G$ is also perfect as its Frobenius endomorphism will indeed be an automorphism (the identity). Is there anything wrong in the argument I present?

Looks fine. In characteristic $0$ the problem is trivial. In characteristic $p$, a field is perfect if and only if the Frobenius map is an automorphism of the field.
